# Undefined variable with $_GET?

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I have this problem in php:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _Get in /.../script/install.php  on line 3
```

and this is the code in line 3:

```
if($_Get['step']<1)
```

so what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Variable names are case sensitive in PHP.

```
if($_GET['step']<1)
```

also, to avoid `notice` level warnings, you may want to check for the existence of the variable first:

```
if ((array_key_exists($_GET, "step")) and ($_GET['step']<1))
```

Comment: @Husain can you show the full code as you are using it right now?

Comment: sure, in this file:
http://www.alsbtain.net/sb3/upload/6684-1-567561314.zip

the problem now is:
Notice: Undefined index: step in /***/script/install.php  on line 3

but it's in the same lines

Comment: @Husain you didn't do what I recommended.

Comment: if you mean this:
if ((array_key_exists($_GET, "step")) and ($_GET['step']<1))

I did it before but then I deleted it again, but the other things they exist already.
any way thank you very much, and I will add this syntax again.

Comment: @Husain the `notice` messages are not really error messages, but they appear when you try to access a variable that doesn't exist. Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that in your url you have the parameter. EG: `install.php?step=1`

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error "undefined variable $_GET" ...  Then I re-install XAMPP, now in the C drive and problem was solved.

I don't know if there was an issue with my previous installation per se, or maybe something XAMPP does not like about logical drives.

Just wanted to share.
Good luck!!

Comment: OP didn't mention XAMPP and may not be using it.